# how do I make a function including a dot

Tags: javascript, function, console.log

I want to make a function called "lib.hello" is that valid syntax and if not how do I do it?
here us my code `function lib.hello(){ console.log("hello") }`

```js
function lib.hello(){
  console.log("hello")
}
```

Comment: `const lib = { hello: () => console.log("hello"); }`. You can then call method like `lib.hello()`

Comment: @Keith In an object, method notation is shorter and preferred: `const lib = { hello(){ console.log("hello"); } };`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way

```
function yourClass() {
}

yourClass.prototype.dotFunction = function() { return 'hello'; };

console.log(new yourClass().dotFunction());
```

Answer (score 1):

first you must create an object next you do it same as bellow.

```js
let Obj = {
  a:1,
  childMethod:(param)=>{console.log(param)}
}
Obj.childMethod("test")
```

Or you can do it by bellow code:

```js
function yourClass() {
}

yourClass.prototype.childMethod = function(parameter) { console.log(parameter); };

var a = new yourClass();
a.childMethod("test");

//or you can do it same as follow

new yourClass().childMethod("test2")
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you asking to do this? This seems like either an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), or an exercise in theory.

As other answers have alluded to, you can make a class named `lib` with a method named `hello`, but that's not quite the same as a function named `lib.hello`.

Here's another variation:

```
let a = {
    'lib.hello' : function() {
        console.log('hello');
    }
}

a['lib.hello']()
```

Technically this is an anonymous function, not a function named `lib.hello`, but it's kind of what you're asking for because it's associated with the key `lib.hello`.